# unable to login to ubuntu after upgrade to 12.10

Tags: unity, 12.10

Ubuntu 12.10 upgrade results in blank screen after login
After upgrading to 12.10, I can't login anymore. The problem seems be related to graphic card (computer is compaq c700) and new unity interface. I wonder if anyone have similiar problems and if some solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to go into recovery mode and uninstall the proprietary driver. Then reinstall it once you are back in on the open source driver. If you still get the same problem, try installing a more recent version of the driver than is available in the repos.